# Buildroot Config Option for Armv8 Architeture

Tags: linux, buildroot, uefi, linaro

I am new to Buildroot and working on using Buildroot to use Linaro as a kernel and build UEFI.

For building UEFI it needs ACPI tools mainly iasl command..
But iasl command available as a part of buildroot cant be executed and gives following error:

"Cant Execute iasl command"

I checked the file type of iasl and found out it is x86 while 
My system on which buildroot is running is x86_64. Not sure if this is the reasom for iasl to be failing..if so how can we specify buildroot to generate x86_64 tools?

error from buildroot logs is:

```
******buildroot-2016.11.2/uefi-image-443bf46/ArmPlatformPkg/ArmVExpressPkg/Library/ArmVExpressSysConfigLib/ArmVExpressSysConfigLib.inf [AARCH64]
Building ... buildroot-2016.11.2/uefi-image-443bf46/ArmPlatformPkg/ArmVExpressPkg/Library/ResetSystemLib/ResetSystemLib.inf [AARCH64]
Building ... /buildroot-2016.11.2/uefi-image-443bf46/ArmPlatformPkg/Library/PL031RealTimeClockLib/PL031RealTimeClockLib.inf [AARCH64]
Building ... /buildroot-2016.11.2/uefi-image-443bf46/ArmPlatformPkg/Library/PL011SerialPortLib/PL011SerialPortExtLib.inf [AARCH64]
Building ... /buildroot-2016.11.2/uefi-image-443bf46/ArmPlatformPkg/ArmVExpressPkg/AcpiTables/rtsm_ve-aemv8a/AcpiTables.inf [AARCH64]
/bin/sh: /buildroot-2016.11.2/output/build/acpica-20160831/generate/unix/bin/iasl: cannot execute binary file
make: *** [/buildroot-2016.11.2/uefi-image-443bf46/Build/ArmVExpress-FVP-AArch64/RELEASE_ARMLINUXGCC/AARCH64/ArmPlatformPkg/ArmVExpressPkg/AcpiTables/rtsm_ve-aemv8a/AcpiTables/OUTPUT/facp.aml] Error 126
build.py...
 : error 7000: Failed to execute command
        make --no-print-directory tbuild [/buildroot-2016.11.2/uefi-image-443bf46/Build/ArmVExpress-FVP-AArch64/RELEASE_ARMLINUXGCC/AARCH64/ArmPlatformPkg/ArmVExpressPkg/AcpiTables/rtsm_ve-aemv8a/AcpiTables]******
```

Please guide me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not giving enough details, but my feeling is that you might have built iasl for the target, and try to run it on the machine where you're running the Buildroot build. Cannot work. Make sure to use the `host-acpica` package.

Comment: Hi Thomas, i am building it for Armv8 architecture and need iasl to build UEFI too..please let me know what details you want to understand more on this..it is kind of urgent for me to resolve it..Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi Thomas, More specifically about the error i have updated the question description